# Status code: 500 Error after installing Magento-2. I cannot view my homepage and unable to login to backend

Tags: magento2, http-status-code-500

I Installed magento 2 using cpanel but after installing when i visit the homepage i got this error following error.

"Status code: 500
The page you are looking for has returned a status code 500 while loading. This usually means that the software this website is using cannot interpret properly its code. If you are the owner of the website, please check (and probably - undo) the following most common reasons for this status code:
"
[See Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfeaO.png)

Comment: Your website hoster likely has a way for you to go through the actual error logs and see what's what: without having a look at those it's pretty much impossible to try and guess what's going on, might be anything, from permissions to DB.

Comment: Thanks Nemoverflow. Yes you are right. I contacted to hoster team and they solve out the issue.